# Django create and submit form manually

Tags: python, django, forms, post

The question is that my form is dynamical. Every time there may be different number of fields depending on data in DB. I am able to render this form manually (by passing attributes and types to template as context). But how can I handle the action of pressing submit button in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have a function into your views.py to render the template, you just basically have to verify if there have been any data posted :

```
def contact(request): # let's say it's a contact form
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        print(request.POST)
        # do your things with the posted data
    else: # form not posted : show the form.
        return render(...)
```

Also please note that you have to manually add `{% csrf_token %}` anywhere between your `<form>` and `</form>` inside your template, which basically add a hidden field to secure your site against Cross Site Request Forgery attacks.

And if you do it like that, just don't put any `action` attribute in your form, so that it posts to the same url.

Comment: I have two more questions! How can i get all posted values? And is it possible with class based views?

Comment: `request.POST.get('field_name')` about class based views, check this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views